# Accessing OUT parameters with Apache Camel SQL Stored Procedure Component

Tags: apache-camel, camel-sql

I'm calling an Oracle Stored Procedure using [Apache Camel's SQL Stored Procedure Component](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-sql/src/main/docs/sql-stored-component.adoc).

The Stored Procedure that I'm calling has several OUT parameters which are all returned in the BODY as a String, for example:

`{param1=0, param2=-, param3=<?xmlversion="1.0"?><Client><Item><PHONE>1234567890</PHONE></Item></Client>}`

Currently I'm tokenizing/parsing the BODY to be able to extract the parameters. This works but it's not efficient (and error prone).

My code looks like this:

```
...
<bean id="od" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
    <property name="driver">
        <bean class="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
    </property>
    <property name="url" value="${connURL}"/>
</bean>
...
<camel:to uri="sql-stored:PACKAGE.STORED_PROCEDURE(VARCHAR ${exchangeProperty.param0},OUT VARCHAR param1,OUT VARCHAR param2,OUT VARCHAR param3,OUT VARCHAR param4)?dataSource=od"> 
...
<!-- I tried this but "abc" always has no value -->
<camel:setHeader headerName="abc">
    <camel:description layoutX="280" layoutY="20" layoutWidth="120" layoutHeight="120"/>
    <camel:simple>$simple{header.param3}</camel:simple>
</camel:setHeader>
<!-- This is how I parse the BODY (inefficient!) -->
<camel:groovy><![CDATA[

    def outParams = [
        param1: "NO_VALUE",
        param2: "NO_VALUE",
        param3: "NO_VALUE",
        param4: "NO_VALUE"   
    ]
    def retERR = "yes"
    def t = ""
    def bd = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)

    try {
        def varList = bd.replaceAll("\n","").replaceAll("^\\{","").replaceAll("\\}\$","")
        varList = varList.tokenize(',')
        for (keyVal in varList) {
            keyVal = keyVal.trim()
            i = keyVal.indexOf('=')
            outParams[keyVal.take(i)] = keyVal.substring(i+1)
        }
        retERR = "no"
    } catch(all) {
        retERR = "yes"
    }

    exchange.setProperty("outParams",outParams)
    exchange.setProperty("retERR",retERR)

]]>
</camel:groovy>
...
<camel:to uri="bean:varpop?method=MYBEAN(&apos;outParams,retERR,param3,abc&apos;)">
    <camel:description layoutX="20" layoutY="470" layoutWidth="120" layoutHeight="120"/>
</camel:to>
```

Is there a direct way of accessing `param1`, `param2`, etc... directly without having to parse the BODY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sql-stored-component` producer already returns `Map` to body. Throw away all your parsing logic, because the String, you are parsing, is just `toString()` representation of `Map`.

```
...
<camel:to uri="sql-stored:PACKAGE.STORED_PROCEDURE(VARCHAR ${exchangeProperty.param0},OUT VARCHAR param1,OUT VARCHAR param2,OUT VARCHAR param3,OUT VARCHAR param4)?dataSource=od"/> 

<!-- Variant 1: Pass Map to MYBEAN method -->
<camel:to uri="bean:varpop?method=MYBEAN(${body})"/>

<!-- Variant 2: Get params from Map and pass it as arguments -->
<camel:to uri="bean:varpop?method=MYBEAN(${body[param1]},${body[param2]},${body[param3]},${body[param4]})"/>
```

And then use it in your `varpop` bean:

```
public class Varpop{
    // Variant 1: Map as argument
    public void MYBEAN(Map<String, String> procedureResult){
        System.out.println(procedureResult.get("param1"));
        System.out.println(procedureResult.get("param2"));
        //...
    }

    // Variant 2: Multiple arguments
    public void MYBEAN(String param1, String param2, String param3, String param4){
        System.out.println(param1);
        System.out.println(param2);
        //...
    }
}
```